# Transforming HTML to Text with the Saxon library in .NET (XSL 2.0)

Tags: c#, html, xml, xslt, saxon

I'm trying to convert HTML markup to text

I'm using the Saxon library since .NET 4.5 does not natively support XSL 2.0.
http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.7HE

When I run my xsl script on http://xslttest.appspot.com/ I don't get any errors and the output is correct.

**HTML Code**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops">
    <head> 
        <title>Test Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Test Header</h1>
    <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
        <p class="center"><img src="ignore.jpeg" alt="ignore"/></p>
    <div class="Test"><p>More Text</p></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="text" media-type="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/xhtml:html">
        <xsl:call-template name="print-it">
            <xsl:with-param name="nodeToPrint" select="xhtml:body"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="print-it">
        <xsl:param name="nodeToPrint"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="matches(lower-case(local-name(.)), 'h[123456]|p|div|title')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(replace(string-join(text(), ''), '''', '')), ' ')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace(string-join(text(), ''), '''', ''))"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:call-template name="print-it">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodeToPrint" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**:

```
    Test Title


Test Header
Blah Blah Blah

More Text
```

However, when I try to do the transformation in .NET, I get an exception. I'm not sure if the issue is with the XSL script and the online converter is forgiving or the Saxon library is dropping the ball.

Exception Message:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in saxon9he.dll

Additional information: The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type.
```

**.NET Code**:

```
using Saxon.Api;

var xslt = new FileInfo(@"C:\path\to\stylesheet.xslt");
var input = new FileInfo(@"C:\path\to\data.xml");
var output = new FileInfo(@"C:\path\to\result.xml");

// Compile stylesheet
var processor = new Processor();
var compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
var executable = compiler.Compile(new Uri(xslt.FullName));

// Do transformation to a destination
var destination = new DomDestination();
using(var inputStream = input.OpenRead())
{
    var transformer = executable.Load();
    transformer.SetInputStream(inputStream, new Uri(input.DirectoryName));
    transformer.Run(destination);
}

// Save result to a file (or whatever else you wanna do)
destination.XmlDocument.Save(output.FullName);
```

**UPDATE**:

Thank you MartinHonnen. Your suggestion worked.

```
Serializer _serializer = new Serializer();
MemoryStream _ms = new MemoryStream();
String _outputStream = new StreamWriter(_ms, new UTF8Encoding(false));
 _serializer.SetOutputWriter(_outputStream);

using (inputStream == input.OpenRead()) {
    XsltTransformer transformer = executable.Load();
    transformer.MessageListener = new SaxtonMessageListener();
    transformer.SetInputStream(inputStream, new Uri(input.DirectoryName));
    transformer.Run(_serializer);
}

String _text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_ms.ToArray());
```

Comment: On what line is the exception thrown?

Comment: Well, the problem is that your stylesheet does not create a well-formed XML document which would fit into a DOM destination but rather a fragment containing only text. I am not sure what you want to do that requires XSLT 2.0 and Saxon, as none of your templates in the stylesheet are used, given that the input has elements in no namespace and your stylesheet matches on the XHTML namespace but that result only fits into http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/DomDestination.html#DomDestination(System.Xml.XmlDocumentFragment). Whether you need a DOM is not clear.

Comment: @Örvar On the transformer.Run(destination); line

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you. I completely overlooked that. I only need the text. Not a well formed DOM. I also updated the HTML example.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - Thank you for the link. This is cleared up allot of things for me. However, I don't see a "destination" object which fits my needs. Do you have any any recommendations?

Comment: So you have used `output method="text"`, what kind of result do you want in the .NET API, a single string with the text or simply a file created with the text?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Just a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want a string or a text file, then you can use http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/Serializer.html and either set http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/Serializer.html#SetOutputFile(string) if you want a file or create a `StringWriter` and pass it to http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/Serializer.html#SetOutputWriter(System.IO.TextWriter), then after the `Run` call you only need to use `ToString()` on the created StringWriter I think.